# datagrid scrollbars not showing in frame

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a DataGrid in a UseraControl. In a separate UserControl I have a frame pointing to the UserControl with the DataGrid. When the application runs, the datagrid is shown in the frame. but the Datagrid's scrollbars are not visible. Not in the conventional sence anyways.

If I place the frame in this mannor, it show the scroll bars.

```
d:DesignHeight="768" d:DesignWidth="1366">

<Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={x:Static app:detailsSQL.Instance}}">
    <Frame ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" Source="/content/membership/members/details/tabs/grid.xaml"/>
</Grid>
```

However if i do this, the scroll bars dissapear, although it's still very capable of scrolling with the mouse wheel.

```
d:DesignHeight="768" d:DesignWidth="1366">

<Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={x:Static app:detailsSQL.Instance}}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Frame Grid.Column="1" Source="/content/membership/members/details/tabs/grid.xaml"/>
</Grid>
```

Even if I don't put the Frame in a GridColumn, it still won't show the scroll bars. Is there a reason why it's this sensitive?

Answer (score 0):

Scrollbar will only show if the available area to draw the control is more than the allocated area. Here  you can put a scrollbar around the grid in your usercontrol.

or if you are intending to make your usercontrol itself scrollable then you might consider to put it around the frame.

eg:

```
<ScrollViewer Height="",Width="">
<Frame Grid.Column="1" Source="/content/membership/members/details/tabs/grid.xaml"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

and try giving your ScrollViewer a size .